# automatically transform text file

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to programming and i have to write a short script like i copied pasted under here can someone help me with that, the language has to be in C#

-- from: .asci file

```
Trashcan1,509103.887 m,5535946.837 m,-1.650 m,PC
Lamp2,509103.407 m,5536024.068 m,-1.771 m,PC
Lamp3,509108.618 m,5536012.905 m,-1.371 m,PC
```

-- to: .sql or .txt

```
INSERT INTO geo (fc, created, the_geom) VALUES ('Trashcan', now(), st_setsrid(gb_makepoint(509103.887,5535946.837),25832))
INSERT INTO geo (fc, created, the_geom) VALUES ('Lamp', now(), st_setsrid(gb_makepoint(509103.407,5536024.068),25832))
INSERT INTO geo (fc, created, the_geom) VALUES ('Lamp', now(), st_setsrid(gb_makepoint(509108.618,5536012.905),25832))
```

-- write a program code, that can automatically transform that

Comment: Why 2nd and 3rd line have same fc value Lamp? Should be Lamp2 and Lamp3

Comment: you want to import a CSV file into a database? Is this MS SQL?

Comment: What are you having problems with? Opening the file, reading the file, writing output, saving the file? Future questions need to be more concise and targeted on what you have an issue with...not *issues* with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `File.ReadLines`, `WriteAllLines` and string methods:

```
var sqlInserts = System.IO.File.ReadLines(inPath)
    .Select(GetInsertFromLine)
    .Where(s => s != null);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(outPath, sqlInserts);
```

and the method `GetInsertFromLine`

```
static string GetInsertFromLine(string line)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
    if(fields.Length < 3) return null;
    string geom1 = fields[1].Split()[0].Trim();
    string geom2 = fields[2].Split()[0].Trim();
    string geom = $"st_setsrid(gb_makepoint({geom1},{geom2}))";    
    return $"INSERT INTO geo (fc, created, the_geom) VALUES ({fields[0]}, now(), {geom}, 25832)";
}
```

But if you don't trust the input file you should not parse it like this. Then you should use `decimal.TryParse` to validate the values and use parameterized queries to insert it into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use *regular expressions* to match `name` and two numbers `first` and `second` which we can insert into query with a help of string interpolation:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

Regex regex = new Regex(
  @"^\s*(?<name>.*?)[0-9]+\s*,(?<first>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\s*m,(?<second>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)");

var result = File
  .ReadLines(@"c:\myFile.txt")
  .Select(item => regex.Match(item))
  .Where(match => match.Success)
  .Select(match => $"INSERT INTO geo (fc, created, the_geom) VALUES ('{match.Groups["name"].Value}', now(), st_setsrid(gb_makepoint({match.Groups["first"].Value},{match.Groups["first"].Value}),25832))");

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MySqlFile.txt", result);
```